# CLIPS: Clear-window in CLIPSDOS.exe and tab to indent in CLIPSIDE

Tags: rule-engine, clips, expert-system

With CLIPS, It's possible some of the following?? (V 6.4 for Windows)

1 - Use a command like (clear-window) in the CLIPSDOS console for clear the console. 
2 - Use tabs for indentation in CLIPSIDE. When i press tab, cursor goes to File menu item... how to indent?

How do people learn programming with CLIPS? I'm using a plugin for Visual Studio that helps me with the parenthesis concordance, let me use tabs to indent, and other tricks. But it has some problems, and i'm quite worried about the usability of the CLIPSDOS and CLIPSIDE interfaces to this purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CLIPSDOS, you can use the command (system cls) to clear the screen. This will simply call out to DOS to execute a cls command.

The IDEs use standard text editing classes for the CLIPS command prompt window. Tabs appear to work correctly on the macOS IDE, but not the Windows or Java Swing IDEs, so that will need to be corrected.

While you can directly enter constructs at the command prompt, it's better to edit them in a file with your preferred text editor and then use the load command from the command prompt to load the contents of that file. The IDE supports a command history so you can use the up/down arrow keys to cycle through prior commands to avoid retyping.